# how do i pass the selected value in my php code?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So i've a dropdown menu of my Languages, the HTML/JS output is like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu  dropdown-menu-right show">
<a class="dropdown-item " ng-click="changeLang('1')">English</a>
<a class="dropdown-item " ng-click="changeLang('2')">Spanish</a>
<a class="dropdown-item active" ng-click="changeLang('3')">French</a>
```

the selected one in the code above is French, (class="dropdown-item **active**")

my PHP code in the controller is this:

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-muted waves-effect waves-dark" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></i></a>
```

As you can see above, whenever i change the value of the dropdown menu, the icon still pointing to French (obviously because hardcoded)

how do i catch the *active* one and refer to it in my PHP code ?

Comment: Before continuing, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: what you mean "how do i catch the active one and refer to it in my PHP code ?" ? What do you want to achive? What is body of your `changeLang` function?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely look into using JavaScript for this - my thought process would be to set a cookie defining the currently selected option and then appending some HTML to the element. This would eliminate the need to catch this server side and re-render the page. Plus it has the added benefit of sending the option to the server on every request in case you need to perform some other action with it.